# Hello world Express app not working

Tags: node.js, express, shared-hosting

I'm working on my first app in godaddy's share hosting. I was told by their tech support that node.js can be installed and work. They pointed me to this tutorial. which I followed without a problem.
https://ferugi.com/blog/nodejs-on-godaddy-shared-cpanel/
So after installing node and npm, I proceded to get my first "hello world" app going. I installed express, not problem here, and this is my app.js file

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

//=========== Express Routes Here ==========//
//default route
app.get("/", function(req, res) 
    res.send("Hello Node.js");
});

//catch all other routes
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    res.send("<h1>Invalid Page</h1>");
});

//server listening on port 8000
app.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log("server started on port 8000");
});
```

and this is the error I'm getting

```
/apps/node/app.js:8
    res.send("Hello Node.js");
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
```

Comment: You're missing an opening `{` on your default route.

Answer (score 2):

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello Node.js");
});
```

You are missing a curly brace in your function inside the call to get().

Comment: thanks, that was part of the problem, but still when open browser and go to http://pctechtips.org/apps/notedtest:8000 I get page not found